# Why does my fork/join deadlock?

Tags: java, groovy, parallel-processing, fork-join

Consider the following snipped of code, which calculates the size of all paths given.

```
def pathSizes = []
paths.each { rootPath ->
  pathSizes.addAll(
    withPool { pool ->
      runForkJoin(rootPath) { path ->
        def headSizes = [:]
        println path

        def lines = ["ls", "-al", path].execute().text.readLines()
        (0..<3).each { lines.remove(0) }
        lines.each { line ->
          def fields = line.split(/\s+/)
          if (fields[0] =~ /^d/)
            forkOffChild("$path/${fields.last()}")
          else {
            def userName = fields[2]
            def fileSize = fields[4] as long
            if (headSizes[userName] == null)
              headSizes[userName] = fileSize
            else
              headSizes[userName] += fileSize
          }
        }

        quietlyJoin()
        System.gc()

        def shallowSizes =
          headSizes.collectEntries { userName, fileSize ->
            def childResult =
              childrenResults.sum {
                 it.shallowSizes[userName] ? it.shallowSizes[userName] : 0
              } ?: 0
            return [userName, fileSize + childResult]
          }

        def deepSizes =
          childrenResults.sum { it.deepSizes ?: [] } +
          shallowSizes.collect { userName, fileSize ->
            [userName: userName, path: path, fileSize: fileSize]
          }

        return [shallowSizes: shallowSizes, deepSizes: deepSizes]
      }.deepSizes
    })
}
```

Why does this snippet of code deadlock? There are no interactions between threads except possibly with the system call and other parts of the Java framework. If the system calls are the problem, then how can I fix it, without removing the system calls (they are slow, hence the need to parallelize)?

Comment: How do you know it's deadlocked? Does a stack dump show that threads are waiting for each other (on a lock or monitor)?

Comment: Also, do you have any subdirectories with pathological names like `foo .`?

Comment: Also, forgive me if this is a learning exercise or just for fun, but is there a reason you're not using the `list` and `length` methods of http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: I know it's deadlocked because of print statements around the join, showing that the join doesn't complete. I replaced it with a getChildrenResults() call and it no longer seems to deadlock, though it's unclear to me what Groovy does differently (maybe there's a difference between get() and join() not apparent from the API documentation?).

Comment: There could be such names but I don't see why they'd be a problem, as the List form of execution was used (similar to adding quotes from the shell but without the mess of special characters).

Comment: There are a few reasons that I'm not using File. First, it is much slower than the native commands. Second, it doesn't allow you to get the username.